# Name of property: $a \circ (a \circ b) = b$

Tags: functions, terminology

How do you describe an operation like this?

$$ a \circ (a \circ b) = b $$

For example, XOR is like this:

$$ a \oplus a \oplus b = b $$

Comment: What are $i$, $x$, and $f$ here? I presume $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $x, i \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: It might be more convenient to write $a\circ b$ instead of $f(a,\,b)$. (Also, the second equation is redundant.) As for the question: In XOR's case this result follows from the operator being associative and self-inverse and having an identity element. I'm not aware of any name for the final result, which is a shame because you might care about functions that get it for other reasons.

Comment: Is the property you have in mind that $$f(i, f(i, x)) = x$$ holds for some fixed $i$ and all $x$ in the domain $X$ of $f$? If so, the property is just that $f(i, \,\cdot\,)$ is an involution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics) If the requirement is that it holds for all $i$ and all $x$ in $X$, then one could say that $f(i, \,\cdot\,)$ is an involution for all $i$, or that the image of the curried function $X \to (X \to X)$, $i \mapsto f(i, \,\cdot\,)$, is contained in the set of involutions of $X$---but I don't know a single term to describe this property.

Comment: Informally, if $f : X \times X \to X$ satisfies this for all $i,x \in X$ then I might view $f$ as being "an involutive action of $X$ on itself".  Slightly more generally, if $f : Y \times X \to X$ satisfies the identity I might say "$f$ is an involutive action of $Y$ on $X$".

Comment: Do you want $f$ to also have this property in the first argument? i.e., $f(f(i,x),x) = i$?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The parameters of $f$ come from the same set, and $f$ maps to that set. Other than that they can be anything

Comment: @eyeballfrog For my specific case (the source of this general question) yes

Comment: @J.G. Edited per your suggestion. Yes a shame because I'd like to ask another question asking for more examples of this kind of function for a specific purpose. Thank you!

Comment: @Travis I'm thinking for all $i$ and $x$ (edited question to be $a$ and $b$). Thank you!

Comment: The new notation either implies associativity or is ambiguous. I suggest using parentheses, i.e., $a \circ (a \circ b) = b$ to make the intent clear.

Comment: @MattThomas "I'd like to ask another question asking for more examples of this kind of function for a specific purpose" I'm not sure whether you should ask a fresh question or edit this one to be about that instead. It doesn't look like you'll get a nice name for this property, but you might get other examples.

Comment: Just one more minor suggestion: Since we're now using an operator notation, i.e., $a \circ b$, rather than the function notation $f(a, b)$, I might adjust to question to ask about operators, rather than functions, that have the desired property.

Comment: @Travis Edited to speak of operators not functions. Thanks. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Perhaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "[A guide to self-distributive quasigroups, or latin quandles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.06609)," David Stanovský calls such an operator **left involutory**.

> A binary algebra $(A,*)$ is called *left involutory* (or *left symmetric*) if $x * (x * y) = y$ (hence we have unique left division with $x \backslash y = x ∗ y$).

It's not a very popular term—it currently only has 8 hits on Google—but it makes sense (since it means that the section function $(x * {})$ is involutory), and there are a couple of other papers which use the same terminology with the same meaning (and at least one of these papers cites Stanovský's paper).

So if you're going to write a paper using this term, I suggest using the term "left involutory," and consider citing Stanovský's paper when you do.

(Fun fact: one of the Google search results for "left involutory" caught my eye because it's a [chat log](https://esolangs.org/logs/2015-12-09.txt) from an IRC chat room that I speak in regularly! I couldn't resist mentioning this.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can rearrange like this, $a \circ (a \circ b) = (a \circ a) \circ b$, then the expression you have implies that $a$ is both the left-inverse and the right-inverse of itself. Hence, $a$ is the inverse of itself.

Comment: If we define an operation on any set $X$ by $x \circ y := y$ then we have $a \circ (a \circ b) = a \circ b = b$, so every element is a left identity but (if $X$ has at least two elements) no right identity, and so no two-sided identity. Since $a \circ (b \circ a) = a$ and $b \circ (a \circ b) = b$, *every* element is an inverse of every other element (where we mean inverse in the sense of regarding $(S, \circ)$ as a regular semigroup).